# Angular creating library: Unable to use 3rd party package types

Tags: angular, typescript, npm, package.json

I am developing own library for voice recognition. I want to use 3rd party package types `@types/dom-speech-recognition`. When I tried to use the types in my service, the compiler was throwing errors that those 3rd party types cannot be found:

```
Error: ../angular-voice-recognition/src/lib/voice-recognition.service.ts:9:23 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'SpeechRecognition'.

9   private speechAPI!: SpeechRecognition;
                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: ../angular-voice-recognition/src/lib/voice-recognition.service.ts:40:28 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'webkitSpeechRecognition'.

40       this.speechAPI = new webkitSpeechRecognition();
                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I've installed these types by `npm install @types/dom-speech-recognition --save`

**tsconfig.lib.json:**

```
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../../out-tsc/lib",
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationMap": true,
    "inlineSources": true,
    "types": [
      "dom-speech-recognition"
    ]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "src/test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

**voice-recognition.service.ts:**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {VoiceParams} from "./model/voice-params.model";
import {Observable} from "rxjs";
import {VoiceResult} from "./model/voice-result";
import {VoiceEvent} from "./model/voice-event";

@Injectable()
export class VoiceRecognitionService {
  private speechAPI!: SpeechRecognition;

  ...

  private initialize(params: VoiceParams) {
    if ('webkitSpeechRecognition' in window) {
       ...
    }
  }
}
```

These are all places which I modified after installing the `@types/dom-speech-recognition` into my library.

Do I need to export or import the type also somewhere else?

Answer (score 1):

The error message you're seeing indicates that the types for SpeechRecognition and webkitSpeechRecognition cannot be found, even though you have install.

Try to change tsconfig.ts:

```
{"compilerOptions": {"types": []}}
```

which allows TypeScript to discover and include the types from installed packages.

And add appropriate import in voice-recognition.service.ts

```
import { SpeechRecognition } from 'dom-speech-recognition';
```